# How can I get the variables filled in for sending by SSH

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a script which should write log entries to a log file on another server. The scripts runs on server SRV1 and should write the entries to server SRV2. The entry gets wirtten in the log file, but the content from the variables is empty.

```
NODE_NAME="SRV1"
BUILD_NUMBER="10"

test() {
  ssh SRV2 'echo `date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"` "${NODE_NAME} #${BUILD_NUMBER} > $1" | tee -a /var/lib/jenkins/logs/packaging.log'
}


test "testmessage"
```

When I run tail -f on the logfile on SRV2 the following there are only empty entries in the logfile:

```
12-11-2014 11:15:45  # >
12-11-2014 11:15:45  # >
12-11-2014 11:19:21  # >
12-11-2014 11:19:21  # >
12-11-2014 11:22:12  # >
12-11-2014 11:22:12  # >
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command within the single quotes is run on the machine you are connecting to. Within single quotes, parameters will be passed literally, then expanded on that machine. You need to expand the parameters in on your local machine advance by wrapping the command in double quotes instead:

```
ssh SRV2 "echo \"$(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')\" '${NODE_NAME} #${BUILD_NUMBER} > $1'  | tee -a /var/lib/jenkins/logs/packaging.log"
```

The escaped double quotes around the command substitution mean that the output of the date command will also be treated as a single word. This is generally perceived as good practice as it avoids problems with word splitting and glob expansion. I have modified your command to use the preferred `$()` syntax instead of backticks, as these are widely considered to be deprecated.

The single quotes around the rest of the string ensure that none of the characters are interpreted by the shell and instead, are printed literally.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I tested it a few minutes ago but it's not working. I don't get an error message but I also don't have an output on the console or an entry in the logfile. I used the command you suggested in your answer. Did you tested it by yourself?

Comment: I think that the problem there is the usage of tee. You are redirecting the output of the echo to the value of `$1`, so there should be no output to stdout. What are you trying to do with tee?

Comment: My idea is to write log messages to the central jenkins server. The jenkins server also has a web gui and there you can see the console output of the server which runs the script (SRV1). With tee, I'm trying to send the log message to the console of SRV1 and into the centralized log file on the jenkins server (SRV2). Does this make sense to you?

Comment: I think so. I have edited my answer so that SRV2 echoes the output to the console and also appends it to the log file. I'm not sure what `$1` was being used for - you haven't mentioned how you were calling your function (this would be the first argument passed to `test` on your local machine).

Comment: I call my function like mentioned in the question `test "log message"`. `$1` should contain the log message that should be sent to the console and logfile.

Comment: It's working now, many thanks! I'll post my final solution in an answer.

Comment: No problem. I was confused by the `>`, as it is also used to redirect the output of a command to a file. If you want to use a literal `>` character, you will need to quote it (as you have done). I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. This is my solution script:

```
NODE_NAME="SRV1"
BUILD_NUMBER="10"

test() {
  ssh SRV2 "echo \"$(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')\" '${NODE_NAME}' '#${BUILD_NUMBER}' '> ${1}' | tee -a /var/lib/jenkins/logs/packaging.log"
}


test "testmessage"
```

Many thanks!